# Using a new WP_Query inside the loop

Tags: php, wp-query, search

I'm trying to query the database to count log entries for file downloads, this is then displayed an the thumbnail when listing search results.

From Search.php
`

```
<?php 

//JAYJAY Get the download count for this listing so we can pass it to the template part

$query_args = array(
        'post_parent'      => get_the_ID(),
        'post_type'        => 'edd_log',
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'fields'           => 'ids',
      );

    
      $query_args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
          'taxonomy'  => 'edd_log_type',
          'field'     => 'slug',
          'terms'     => 'file_download',
        )
      );
    
    $logs = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    $loveCount = $logs->post_count;

    get_template_part('includes/loop-search-listings', null, array('tpetLoveCount' => $loveCount));
```

`
If I change $loveCount to a fixed number and comment out the query, the functionality works to show the number as needed on the front end, so it seems that this query is not running even though the same query works elsewhere on the website.

Can anyone help me to understand why this query is not working or help me with a workaround?

Many thanks.

var_dump output:

`string(1049) "SELECT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) LEFT JOIN ( wp_term_relationships INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id INNER JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id ) ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_parent = 767254 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (10) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'edd_log' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) OR ( wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy IN( 'category', 'post_tag' ) AND wp_terms.name LIKE '%wellbeing%' AND wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status IN( 'publish','private' ) ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC "`

Comment: When you set `fields` as `ids` the query returns an array of IDs, not a query object. So `$logs->post_count` won't work. Try `count( $logs )`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie `$logs->post_count` does work. It's just that `$logs->posts` will be an array of post IDs instead of objects.

Comment: @JayLoftus try inspecting the SQL query - `var_dump( $logs->request );` - and share the dump output, or just check for yourself whether the query is good.

Comment: I've attached a var_dump - thanks for your help

Comment: @SallyCJ (forgot to tag!)

Comment: if this code is running in search.php there's no `get_the_ID()` because it's an archive page. so, `'post_parent' => get_the_ID()` won't work. What's the var_dump from a page where it works? We'll want both to compare & find where they're different

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the following code is at fault:

```
$query_args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
          'taxonomy'  => 'edd_log_type',
          'field'     => 'slug',
          'terms'     => 'file_download',
        )
      );
```

It seems to be combining the tax_query args with those from the search query itself, by removing this I am getting a better result, although it is counting ALL logs, not just those with the 'file_download' id.

For me it works as downloads are in the hundreds/thousands and some posts maybe have 3-5 other logs that get counted too.

A half fix, but functional for now unless anyone can figure out a way of getting the query to recognise a separate set of tax args?

Thanks guys! :)

Comment: I don't know what added that OR condition having the `AND wp_terms.name LIKE '%wellbeing%'`, but I would try to find the code which added that and modify the code (or if it's a plugin, then try changing the settings) so that the OR is not added to all `WP_Query` calls. And actually, if you just want to know the total number of posts for a specific query, you don't have to set `posts_per_page` to `-1` and instead, set it to `1` and then use the `$found_posts` property (e.g. `$logs->found_posts`) to get the total number of posts.